# knockoutjs style is not binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have the following template for knockout.js:

```
        <script type="text/html" id="feed-template">
            <li data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: BackColor, backgroundImage: 'none' }"   >
                <a style="text-shadow: none" href="#" data-bind="click: ItemClicked">
                    <h1 style="WHITE-SPACE: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold" data-bind="text: PatientName"></h1>
                    <p style='white-space: normal;' data-bind="text: Description"></p>
                    <p style='white-space: normal;' data-bind="text: FeedEvent"></p>
                    <p style='white-space: normal;' data-bind="text: FeedTimeString"></p>
                    <span class="ui-li-count" data-bind="text: DisplayCount"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- ko if: ShowDelete -->
                    <a style="background: none; text-shadow: none;" href="#ConfirmUnfollowPopup" data-transition="pop" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-icon="delete" data-role="button"  data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-bind="click: UnfollowClicked"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </li>
        </script>
```

The template is being bound to an ObservableArray of plain javascript objects, using a foreach: binding. All of the object properties are binding correctly except BackColor. BackColor is a property, not a function, and it's value is always a correct CSS color (e.g., #556677); however, it is bound in the DOM simply as BackColor, not its value.

This template and binding worked in knockout.js 2.1, but I'm migrating it to knockout.js 3.0, where it does not work.

I've tried adding a function to the javascript object that returns the CSS color, and binding to `ShowBackColor()` but this generates a javascript error deep in knockout.

Any suggestions on getting this background style color to bind correctly?

Comment: Can you provide your viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting quotes around backgroundColor.

```
data-bind="style: { 'backgroundColor': BackColor, 'backgroundImage': 'none' }"
```

Comment: No, doesn't make any difference. BackColor is still not binding.

Comment: Can you show the view model? Your other option is to use a CSS binding instead. That might be the simplest solution.

Comment: Another issue that it could be is that BackColor is from the template's parent binding. Maybe it should actually $parent.BackColor?  Hard to tell without seeing the VM and binding.

Comment: The original author did not use a viewmodel as such, and I wish I'd had time to rewrite properly. However, BackColor is a property of the object being bound, as are ItemClicked, PatientName, Description, FeedEvent, FeedTimeString, DisplayCount, and ShowDelete. All others bind correctly. Also, as noted originally, BackColor bound correctly in knockout.js 2.1; it only fails in 3.0.

Comment: What do you mean, not a "viewmodel as such"? Do you mean there are no observables?

Comment: There is an ObservableArray that is in the javascript global space, and is bound (ko.applyBindings()) to the DOM element containing the binding. The original code executed this binding every time the observable array was loaded with new content; however, the newer version of knockout restricted observables to being bound only once, and this has been fixed.

Comment: I don't know the internals of ko. It seems weird to applybindings directly to an observable array. Have you tried wrapping your observableArray within view model and then bind to that? You can keep your global array so you don't need to change a lot of code, just point to it in the viewmodel like so: var myViewModel = {
    Patients: globalPatientsObservableArrayName
}; then use ko.applyBindings(myViewModel). You would then add a data-bind="with:Patients" to a containing div in your html so you wouldn't need to change anything else in the HTML either.

Comment: I'll agree that the code is not the best (as I said, "original author did not" etc.) and a rewrite is called for, although I wasn't given schedule time for it. What's really bugging me is that all the rest of the knockout bindings (for several observables and observable arrays) is working correctly. It's just this one property that isn't binding.

Comment: My last suggestion wouldn't require a rewrite. Also, have you tried Knockout 3.1?

Comment: Given the application code, yes, it's a significant rewrite, not total by any means, but it's pretty data-intensive. Given that the feature is in test now and this is the only known bug, it's up to the powers-that-be how much work they want to put into fixing it. That would include knockout 3.1, since library upgrades always risk breakage. Since I'm working in a branch, though, I can always give it a try and roll back if necessary.

Comment: Please replicate the same in the Jsfiddle. So that we can look onto both the view and view model.

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat by using attr binding. This is a workaround, not a solution (I have the same problem):

```
data-bind="attr: { style: 'background-color: ' + BackColor() + '; background-image: none' }"
```